# Install one package from Debian sid on Debian Wheezy?

Tags: debian, apt, debian-wheezy

I need the `python-statsd` which is only in [Debian (sid)](https://packages.debian.org/sid/python-statsd).

What are the steps to install this package under `Debian Wheezy` please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pip` to install python packages instead.

`pip search python-statsd` => "statsd is a client for Etsy's node-js statsd server. A proxy for the Graphite stats collection and graphing server."

To install statsd use `pip install python-statsd`

Comment: Well it's this package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-statsd but I get the idea.